# Accessing QGIS Interface in standalone PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, extents, interface

I try to set the extent of my `QgsProject` to the extent of one of the layers in it. I know how to do that with `qgis.utils.iface` but it works only when the script runs inside QGIS' Python console. What I need is a way to modify the interface without being in QGIS.

Comment: Do you want to run a standalone application based on qgis written in python? https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts